Use VBA to start and stop Excel Data Streamer
Is there any way to connect, start and stop the Excel Data Streamer using VBA ?  All Microsoft help shows only how to do this manually.  No answers on this forum that I could find.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
